# Is it possible to install multiple instances of a software on a VM using containers?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have to install 2 instances of Azure Integration Runtime on a strictly Windows 10 IaaS VM on Azure.

This is the software in question - [Azure Data Factory Integration Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39717)

Problem is, only one instance is allowed to be run at a time. Is it possible to use containers(virtual environments within this VM) to install more instances?

Just to clarify, I am aware that the integration runtime can be shared, but due to administrative reasons, this is not going to be allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please elaborate the use case ? 
We can share a SHIR between two ADF , if that helps

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-shared-self-hosted-integration-runtime-powershell

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that in the original question, I will not be able to share the IR due to an administrative decision.